# q-points weighting factor in QE

Tags: density-functional-theory, phonons, q-points

When using Quantum Espresso to perform phonon calculations, one can specify a grid of q-point using ldisp=.true. (Monkhorst-Pack grid)

If I ask for a AxBxC grid, the code will reduce this grid taking under consideration the symmetry. Some of these points will then have a higher weight factor.

I want to calculate thermodynamics properties, so I should consider these weighting factors in my average, however QE does not print them anywhere (I believe).

Am I wrong here, or should I retrieve the weights myself?

Comment: I have just seen that before diagonalising the dynamical matrix it is written: "Number of q in the star = X" which gives you the weight, should I close the question or answer it myself?

Comment: Okano, please do answer it yourself!